# How to display date format in highchart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to display date format on the Y axis in Highchartjs graph , but i can't figure out the correct date format , I would be grateful for any help :)

```
  var datas = new Array();
    var option = {
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'xy',
      styledMode: true },
    yAxis: [ {
        labels: {
          format: '{value: %H:%M:%S}', // what the correct format ??}  }{       
        labels: {
          format: '{value} S',
          style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]  }  },
        opposite: true } ],
    series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        data: [],
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: ''
        } } ] };
async function prettyGraph13() {
    const res = await $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/graph/graph/index8",
    async : true,
    success: function( response ) {
        $.each(JSON.parse(response), function (key, val) {
            $.each(val, function (key2, val2) {
            categoriess.push(parseInt(key2.toString()))
            datas.push(parseInt(val2)) // pushing data here ??? i get only the hours 
            datase22.push(val2.timestamp)
            option.series[0].data = datas;
            }) }) }  })
    return res; }
```

Comment: Hi! At first glance, you use `labels.format` twice for one axis which is incorrect. Please, reproduce your example in the working demo with the sample data that you use. You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s1bpqnuo/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, here is my complete graph code, with the data I want to display in date format.
https://jsfiddle.net/awz0bsLo/

Comment: Thanks for providing the data. The reason for the issue is the wrong data format. You need to use `timestamp` format in the case of `datetime` type axis. Check API Reference and the following articles for clarifying: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type , https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro, https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting